slight compression artifacts when processing images with canvas
I have noticed some tiny compression after using canvas and javascript to process the image.
The left side is processed and the right side is raw, they are both in jpeg format. What I do is load the raw image to canvas then read data from the canvas and save it as a file.
I need to make some edits to the image like adding a watermark. Currently, I'm using canvas but my project is sensitive to image quality, so I tried to avoid any unexpected compression.
I'm looking for a method that can avoid this kind of compression. My project is mainly written in JavaScript, so having a solution based on JS would be the best option (frontend solutions and serverside solutions are both ok for me).
THANKS.


There will always be some generational loss taking a JPEG image around a decode to image space and re-encode loop even if you keep all of the compression parameters exactly the same. Some decoders and chroma samplings are worse than others for this. I don't know how good or bad canvas is at this. Smart transcoders do exist that copy all unchanged JPEG blocks verbatim in coefficient space and only modify and recompress those blocks which have changed in the editor. Lossless JPEG image cropping is also possible with the right tools.

I did some research later, and there are two API that can set image quality.
canvas.toBlob(callback, type, quality)

canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions)

the quality parameter in toBlob and the encoderOptions parameter in toDataURL are used to set the image quality with a range from 0 to 1.
I have tested with canvas.toBlob(callback, type, quality). Setting the quality as 1 seems to have reduced the unexpected compression. Here is the test sample with the same image up there.
test sample

If you do that then you end up with a potentially much larger JPEG file than you started with that preserves JPEG artefacts introduced by the original JPEG compression. Ideally you want first generation JPEG files made from lossless compressed images if image quality is paramount.

@MartinBrown Thanks, I have also noticed this problem. I will use it as a temporary solution since my project is so sensitive to image quality that the storage space problem is not the first priority. I will try to improve it later.
